# What are those new terms that MicroSoft has introduced with Windows 8/8.1?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

What are "Rollup"? What about "ESDs"? I wonder if there is/are some another, if so... could you enlighten me? please

This is not my natural language, so... please, sorry for the way I talk english.

Thanks

EDIT: I did a research, but unfortunatelly i had no luck... maybe i am too noob to understand them in another language. Maybe i have to find one that is explained for dummies. Anyways i didn't find the right one

Comment: You need to do some research on your own instead of asking people to list and explain every new term introduced by MS in Windows 8 and 8.1.

Comment: I did, but unfortunatelly i had no luck... maybe i am too noob to understand them in another language. Maybe i have to find one that is explained for dummies. Anyways i didn't find the right one.

Comment: ESD = [Electronic Software Delivery or Download](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_software_delivery). [Rollup or Update Rollup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/824684) is hardly a new term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question regarding the ESD  is a valid question because it is a rather new approach. In Windows 8 and Windows 10 it stands for "Electronic Software Distribution" (or Delivery).

Microsoft uses those files for distributing major system updates - updates that replace the whole system. An example is the distribution of new builds for the Windows 10TP test system.

You can convert an ESD to an ISO if you prefer to make a clean install rather than an upgrade or like to burn an installation DVD for backup. I have developed a little package that allows you to do that. The process is very easy. It contains:

- A Readme explaining the procedure
- A video that shows how it is done
- A tool that does the actual conversion

You can download the **[package from my OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=475A0A48CA6D4035&id=475a0a48ca6d4035%212617)**. Right click on the tile for download. Then unzip (extract) the downloaded folder.